# Thank You message not displayed after Form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

I was trying to display a thank you message in the same page after the submission of a form. However, even though the form gets submitted correctly, the message does not gets displayed.

I'm using the following javascript to cater to this:

```
$(function () 
        {
            $('form').submit(function (e) 
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) 
                    {
                        if(result.indexOf("success") > -1)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("thankyou_message").style.display = "inline";
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

The response of the url is something like this:

```
{"result":"success","data":...
```

I've my code in the following codepen URL: http://codepen.io/abbor123/pen/EgjLdR

Can you please throw some light into the issues with my coding that is hampering the display of the text in the page?

P.S.: I'm a beginner and hence I request you to be gentle on me. :)

Thanks.
AB

Comment: Does your code go inside the `if` block?

Comment: There are many things. One your result response in your example is not a array so indexOf will not work. Two is this a json response? Have you checked to make sure it is being parsed?

Comment: based on your return JSON, you want to check if `result['result']` is success, not just `result` which contains the entire JSON

Comment: Why not just `$('#thankyou_message').css({'display', 'inline'});`? You're already using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the response you posted, I assume that you got a json response. then you can check it like this.

```
success: function(response) {
    if(response.result == 'success') {
      document.getElementById("thankyou_message").style.display = "inline"; 
    } else {
      document.getElementById("thankyou_message").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

check this sample code, which returns a json response.
https://gist.github.com/rashivkp/ef581ea4f4d4e7fba90086ea2c6bb5d2

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should try this code if your sample data is right :

```
if(result.result.indexOf("success") > -1){
 document.getElementById("thankyou_message").style.display = "inline";
}
```

You are doing indexOf in JSON object you should do this on the string

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Answer (score -1):

try replace:

```
document.getElementById("thankyou_message").style.display = "inline";
```

to:

```
$('#thankyou_messa').fadeIn();
```